# Cumulative plot with % on y axis with data from panda DF

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The goal is to plot something like this:
[image]

With this dummy df:

```
columns = ['number_of_words', 'occurrences']
data = [[1, 2312252],
       [2,1000000],
       [3,800000],
        [4, 400000],
        [5, 100000],
        [6, 70000],
        [7, 40000],
        [8, 10000],
        [9, 4000],
        [10, 50]]
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just divide by the sum:

```
plt.plot(dummy_df.number_of_words, 
         dummy_df.occurrences/dummy_df.occurrences.sum()
        )
```

Output:

[image]